# C# htmlagilitypack not returning node from xpath it provided

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Trying to get an xpath and then display the contents of the inner text of that xpath.

```
    private void htmlDocument_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement element = this.wbrBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);

        var savedId = element.Id;
        var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        element.Id = uniqueId;

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(element.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml);
        element.Id = savedId;

        var node = doc.GetElementbyId(uniqueId);
        var xpath = node.XPath;
        lblXpath.Text = xpath;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = w.Load(lstURL.Text);
        var price = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(lblXpath.Text);
        if (price != null) lblPrice.Text = price.InnerHtml;
    }
```

price is always null.  Why is it that htmlagilitypack is not getting the element that it provided the xpath for?

Comment: What does the generated xpath look like? i.e. is it sensible?

Comment: /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/span[2]

Comment: Maybe that part is generated by javascript codes? Try to save the `HtmlDocument` on `button1` click event to check this